Is this suitable for Negative Binomial Regression?
I am using SPSS to run a negative binomial regression for my research project. My dependent variable is 'Number of Days Went to the Gym' in a week, and my independent variable is income (along with a series of controls). The mean for the DV is 3.2 and standard deviation is 2.5; so variance is > mean - which I believe suggests overdispersion(?).
When running a negative binomial regression on SPSS I get the following goodness-of-fit statistics and wondered if they are any cause for concern or not?

Deviance = 0.693 (Value/df)
Pearson Chi Squared = 0.482 (Value/df)
Log Likelihood = -39507.671
Likelihood Ratio Chi Squared = p < 0.001

Note: These statistics have the Negative Binomial dispersion parameter fixed at 1 - I am not sure if/how this impacts the overall model.
Thank you - just looking for some confirmation if this is the correct approach?

One quick observation. Looking at the mean and variance of the dependent variable before you fit a model is not going to tell you whether there is overdispersion. Even if the number of gym days is Poisson distributed, every individual has a different mean (depending on their income, etc.), so the observed data will be a mixture of Poissons.

I would start by fitting a Poisson regression then looking closely for any evidence of overdispersion.

@DoctorMilt What statistics would I check to see for evidence of overdispersion? Sorry I've been trying to teach myself this for the past couple of days!!

Try this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66586/is-there-a-test-to-determine-whether-glm-overdispersion-is-significant

Note the comments to your almost-identical question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/644022/running-a-negative-binomial-regression-with-overdispersion should have done away with your belief that the mean and std. deviation for your DV indicate overdispersion - a point which @DoctorMilt has made above.

In addition to the other comments, if the conditional mean is less than the conditional variance, that suggests underdispersion, not overdispersion.
